# processing JSON data gives PHP Notice & PHP Warning in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

2019 server running IIS with FastCGI/PHP/MSSQL
I receive JSON data from external source. The script works most of the time:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

/* change json into array */
function decode_json($json) {
    $j = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    return $j;
}

/* store json in a text file for logging/debugging */
function save_log($dir, $extn, $text) {
    file_put_contents($dir . time() . "." . $extn, $text);
}

$jd = decode_json($json);
$log = save_log('./Logs/', 'txt', $json);

foreach($jd['Records'] as $r){
    //extract needed data
    //save to DB
}
```

But in some cases I get a 500 error with this response:

> PHP Notice:  Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown on line 0

> PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0

If I take JSON data saved in the log file (17KB) and split it in half and re-send each half separately it will get processed with no errors. This makes me think that there is a limit on size somewhere, but this is only 17KB of data and I could not find where the limit would come from.

In php.ini I have memory limits in MB, and windows TEMP directory is added to the open_basedir and upload_tmp_dir, and sys_get_temp_dir() reports the TEMP directory above. I am not sure how to continue troubleshooting this.

Comment: This is not an error, this is a notice. See [this request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69489). Basically, it's just telling you that it has fallen back to the system's default temp dir, as opposed to something more specific that you have provided. You can override it to something more specific (like a temp dir specifically for this app) or disable notices via error_reporting().

Comment: is there a reason to sometimes fall back to the system default temp dir? Because this works 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: You can try steps above.